# the apostrophe in xeLatex

Tags: xetex

I am writing a long article and I am using `xeLatex` as compiler. However, I have problem for apostrophe representation. Indeed, I changed the compiler to `PdfLatex` and the apostrophe problem was solved, But I got new errors. By the way, I wan to use `xeLatex` and have the right representation for apostrophe.

for example I have `Lets now` instead of `Let's now`. the bellow is the whole code. How can I solve this issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0, 130, 230}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm , textwidth=18cm, textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
\title
{
COMPUTER
NETWORKING 
}
\author
{
    Alireza 
}

\begin{document}
Let’s now
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Let's go
\end{document}` should work. If not then there might be a package that you are using, in this case post a MWE that illustrates your issue.

Comment: what is MWE? you mean the preamble content?

Comment: @Alireza A MWE is a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) . Start with the code provided by Phelype and add whatever font or package that causes the problem.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0, 130, 230}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm , textwidth=18cm, textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}

Comment: can you edit the example into your question, use the code (`{}`) button so line ends preserved, also make it a complete small document that typesets the text with a bad apostrophe. see the example in the first comment

Comment: You don't explain what the problem is. To compile this with XeLaTeX you need to remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and instead add `\usepackage{fontspec}`.  See [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984)

Comment: The document runs in xetex and makes [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaaBm.png)  what is wrong with that?  It isn't clear why you expect apostrophe handling to be different between xelatex and pdflatex

Comment: @David I copied the text from a book. it is 'Let’s now' and this creates the problem. I must write 'Let's now'. this was the cause of problem. did you get the point?

Comment: It should not matter which apostrophe is in your source code `'` or `’`, both should work in regular text. So your example still doesn't show us what the problem is.

Comment: @Alireza  no your point is completely unclear! You need to edit the example so that it is _an example of the problem_  you should use left and right quotes for the quotation `let's now' (or you can use  ‘Let’s now’  with curly quotes, to get the same output, but this should give essentially the same output in pdftex or xetex

Comment: If your latex is dated 2015 or older you may need to add `\usepackage{fontspec}` when using xelatex.

Comment: Have you checked that your `.tex` file has been saved as UTF-8?

Comment: show the log file you get from the document you have posted, do you get a warning about `missing character`

Comment: @David Carlisle , thanks. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

one of the comments is right.

since my latex is dated 2015, I need to add `\usepackage{fontspec}` when using xelatex. thanks David